# How to create a table of six equally spaced columns in latex?

Tags: tables, spacing, columns

I am new to latex. The task of creating columns seems to be too complicated to do it in latex with all the different commands and packages available for creating a simple table of six equi-spaced columns. I want my columns to fit within in the page width and have borders. I also have a heading box which spans the entire length of the table. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! You have to be more specific, what you describe can be done in several ways. What horizontal alignment do you need for the cells (c, l, r, ...)? and how would you like your text wrap? etc ...

Comment: I want the contents of my table to be center aligned. The heading should be in bold. I also want thick outer border for the table and thin borders between cells (internal borders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution here is to use [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| *{6}{X} |}
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{This is a heading column} \\
    \hline
    One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six        \\
    1   & 2   & 3     & 4    & 5    & 6          \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```